# 16003 Items and Counting

Tags: 2010, document-library, limitations

I have a library that has 16003 items and counting in it.

It is a library that supports a company with multiple users.

Is there a way to increase the threshold?

It is in 2010 but could we move it to a newer SharePoint?

Comment: Why do you need to increase a threshold? Do you get an error? If it's the case, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at the web application level in Central Admin:

1. Go to Application Management > Manage Web Applications
2. Click the web application
3. Click the General Settings drop down and choose Resource Throttling

From here, you can see and change the threshold for the web application.

Note that:

> This is risky, since a larger limit increases the possibility of affecting the performance for some or all users.

This is related to switching from row level locking to table level locking for SQL queries that return more than 5000 rows.

Ref: [Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#ID0EAABAAA=Server)

This article also has a number of options for working with large lists other than raising the threshold, which may be useful in some situations.

In general, when making a change like this, you need to test and monitor performance. There are many factors that can affect how changing this will affect your performance including:

1. Your hardware/architecture
2. How many users
3. How many site collections you have per content database (since table level locking will affect the entire content database)

I have seen the limit raised quite a bit in environments with many users and tons of data, without having a serious affect on perceived performance, but we also had a ton of very beefy hardware. I've also seen a single poorly designed list that exceeded this threshold cause serious performance degradation.

Comment: You should add what the impact to changing the threshold might be and the reason why it exists as it’s important to know what you are actually changing.